# Redraw the page after heavy javascript usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page in which I use javascript heavily, I use jquery, extjs, tinymce and bunch of other things in the same place.

Sometimes when I open Jquery dialog the page breaks, look at this screen shot

[image: Broken Jquery Dialog]

Then when I move the dialog a little bit, thins start looking better, but there are still some issues, look at the header of the dialog for example it's not a complete rectangle anymore

[image: Looking better after moving]

Is there anything that can be done about this? like redrawing the page or something like that?

Upon requests, here is the code that opens this dialog, what it does is that it receives an initial value, then it will open the dialog and return the callback function with the new value if user clicks on OK

http://pastebin.com/2Zi4Fymc

Comment: Post your code, there's little we can figure out without it. Thanks!

Comment: Is it only one browser that does this, or is it all?

Comment: Ryan, it's virtually impossible I would have to work like 5 days to be able to bring that part out of the system

Comment: We can't do much without a code so you have to try debug it by yourself. It can fail for various of reasons. Most probably it's the editor iside your dialog that is causing the problems.

Comment: Thank you WTK, I added the code for the part that opens that dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that we would have to see your code to do anything serious about it... In the meantime, if it's better when you move it, why don't you try moving it programmatically (say, 1 px, then back), to force it to redraw?